# What is the best way for making View like this in android ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-tv

I am working on android TV .  I want to make View like this in an activity. 
 [image: First View pop up like this siblings stays out of focus]

[image: SO when user select another sibling view it get focus and whole parent view get rotate]
First View pop up and have focus but siblings stays out of focus,SO when user select another sibling view it get focus and whole parent view get rotate
A view can have listview gridview in side. 
I know ViewPager,RecyclerView,Fragments or more i know Presenters and many stuff from the Leanback Library . but i want to do this with the best way for usability.
Any Suggestion Please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code, layout xmls please. Otherwise your question is to broad.

Comment: brother I am asking for suggestion . I don't have tried because in between i don't want to change my flow . I don't have much time so i start testing everything one by one . I can code or style . RecyclerView can help it out but May be that is not a good approach. Even I can animate item like this . But in TV what can be the good case ?